# Store items in sessionStorage that has ben pushed in another function

Tags: javascript, sessionstorage

I've a slight problem with my code.

I have an array that stores values and i need to store them into sessionStorage.

```
document.getElementById("submit-button").addEventListener("click", book, false);

var array = new Array;

function book()
{

 var seat;

 // value in label that is changed everytime i click on a element.
 seat = document.getElementById("label").innerHTML;

 // Put it in a global array
 array.push(seat);
 window.sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(array));


 booked(seat);


}
```

and in load() function:

```
function load()
 {
  var storedArray = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("items"));


  for (var i = 0; i < storedArray.length; i++)
  {
    var str1 = "seat";
    var str2 = storedArray[i];


    var number = document.getElementById(str1.concat(str2));
    var context = number.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(0,0, seat18.width, seat18.height);
  }

 }
```

But my problem is that every time i call `book()` function, the array resets itself and pushing the new value. And in `load()` function, the `storedArray` in only register the newest value from the Array.

First, i want to store every value that is made in `book()` in global array and get every value in `load()` from getItem. How can i make that possible?

Comment: Could you please provide a jsbin that reproduces the problem(code snippets cannot edit session storage)?

Comment: @Kaddath, you're right. The array should be lost, my bad. But i want to add every item FROM the array to the sessionStorage. But it only store the latest thing from the array. 

Is it any way that it can store (in same sesssion) everytime the array updates and send new values in to the sessionStorage?

Comment: @Kaddath, i've tried to provide a jsbin AND fiddle but it doesn't work. I have copied all my code but the problem remains..

Comment: yes i understand what you're saying, but it doesnt work to paint the canvas and the click eventlistener who paints the canvas in another color doesn't work either. so fiddle is useless in this point..

Answer (score 0):

The `sessionStorage` can persist only until the current session expires. Use `localStorage` instead.

> Data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends.
>   A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores.

Comment: But i have to use sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify. So I want my array (which is converted to a string) inserted into SetItem in sessionStorage to be stored each time I use book (). Then each string will be presented in getItem in load ().